# How to prevent import (and get mock instead of module) in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I'm writing unittests for `MyClass` in `mymodule` that uses
`keras.models.load_model`. Every time when I run my unittests importing keras library took a few seconds and print the message: "Using TensorFlow backend."
such behavior is quite annoying.  Is there a possibility to prevent importing
module in python2.7 (and get Mock() instead)?

mymodule.py:

```python
from keras.models import load_model

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
    """I use load_model here"""
...
```

test_mymodule.py

```python
import unittest

from mock import Mock, MagicMock, patch

from mymodule import MyClass

class MyClassInitializationTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_super_test(self):
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I'm not familiar with the keras lib, I think that you can make you test working by using a combination of MagicMock and modules patching.

mymodule.py:

```
import keras


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """I use load_model here"""
        self.example = keras.models.load_model()
```

test_mymodule.py:

```
import unittest
import sys
from mock import Mock, MagicMock, patch

sys.modules['keras'] = MagicMock() # as to be done before importing mymodules
from mymodule import MyClass

class MyClassInitializationTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('keras.models.load_model')
    def test_my_super_test(self, mock_load_model):
        """ super test """
        fake_return_value = "bar"
        mock_load_model.return_value = fake_return_value
        foo = MyClass()
        self.assertEqual(foo.example, fake_return_value)
        mock_load_model.assert_called_once()
```

When I run my test I've got the expected result:

```
$ nosetests
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.016s

OK
```

I'll try to explain a bit more (I'm not an expert in unittest or mocking). First you will notice that I've change the import of your keras library. This is simply for avoiding mocking `keras`, then `keras.models` and finally `keras.models.load_model`. I add the MagicMock to my available modules (I don't have it installed). The MagicMock as to be before importing `keras`, I you case before importing `mymodule`.

After that, I patch `keras.models.load_model` for my unittest `test_my_super_test`. You receive your mocked method as attribute of your test, I've named the attribute `mock_load_model`. You can use this mocked method to define its return value. That is what I did on the line `mock_load_model.return_value = fake_return_value`. When I will call load_model, the method will return `fake_return_value`. The rest is plain unittest.

Hope it help.
To the rest of the community, please correct me if there is someting wrong with this or if there is a better way to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

I tried before to do `sys.modules['keras'] = MagicMock()` but that's raises an error.

To not change mymodule.py I'd prefer mock all keras submodules like so:

    `sys.modules['keras'] = MagicMock()`
    `sys.modules['keras.models'] = MagicMock()`
   `sys.modules['keras.models.load_model'] = MagicMock()`

Comment: Nice, this is also doable as I was saying. Please make your question as resolved if you don't have no further question.